# How to change the background-color of the autocompletion of the inputs with Angular Material?

Tags: angular, input, autocomplete, angular-material

I don't know why the **old entries propositions** of my input are in **dark** color.
**Initial state :**
[image]

And when I **click** on the input field :

[image]

I imagine we can configure it with some **CSS** ?
I use the prebuilt `purple-green.css` theme.

"aaa" and "moi" are my **previous / former** entries of the input field. It is not a list for a choice!

**component.html :**

```html
<form #form="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="submit(form)">
  <div mat-dialog-content>
    <div>
      <span class="label-for-input">
        <label>Nom du marché :</label>
      </span>
      <mat-form-field class="input-full-width">
        <input matInput id="nomMarche" name="nomMarche" required placeholder="Nom du marché" [(ngModel)]="marche.nomMarche">
      </mat-form-field>
    </div>
    <div>
      <span class="label-for-input">
        <label>Lieu du marché :</label>
      </span>
      <mat-form-field class="input-full-width">
        <input matInput id="lieuMarche" name="lieuMarche" required placeholder="Lieu du marché" [(ngModel)]="marche.lieuMarche">
      </mat-form-field>
    </div>
    <div>
      <span class="label-for-input">
        <label>Jour du marché :</label>
      </span>
      <mat-form-field class="input-full-width">
        <input matInput id="jourMarche" name="jourMarche" required placeholder="Jour du marché" [(ngModel)]="marche.jourMarche">
      </mat-form-field>
    </div>
    <div>
      <span class="label-for-input">
        <label>Heure de début:</label>
      </span>
      <mat-form-field class="input-full-width">
        <input matInput id="heureDebutMarche" name="heureDebutMarche" required placeholder="Heure de début" [(ngModel)]="marche.heureDebutMarche">
      </mat-form-field>
    </div>
    <div>
      <span class="label-for-input">
        <label>Heure de fin :</label>
      </span>
      <mat-form-field class="input-normal-width">
        <input matInput id="heureFinMarche" name="heureFinMarche" required placeholder="heure de fin" [(ngModel)]="marche.heureFinMarche">
      </mat-form-field>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div>
    <div class="containerDroiteDialog">
      <button type="submit" mat-raised-button color="primary" class="marginBottom">Enregistrer
      </button>
      <button type="button" mat-raised-button class="marginBottom" (click)="onCloseClick()">Annuler</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: You can add your own custom css. But before that using chrome dev tools you need to inspect and find classes.

Comment: @SagarKhatri I can't check this part with chrome devtools because it disappears when we lose the focus! :o(

Comment: Which part is the "old entries proposition"? Can you please explain a bit

Comment: @SudiptoMukherjee "aaa" and "moi" are my previous / former entries of the input field.

Comment: "aaa" and "moi" are looking like autocomplete options :) . Can you share your html code responsible for rendering that part so that we can understand better?

Comment: Sorry to say but even after looking at your html its hard to understand where are you populating the old entries? In a tooltip? Or in the input of Lieu du marché. If you are populating it in tooltip can you please show us the code for that. Or do you need to change the background of input?

Comment: @SudiptoMukherjee When you click on a field that you ever setted before, automatically your old entries are present as a list than you can select (to fill the field) instead of typing your new response. It is just what occurs here, and it is black, not white. In fact I don't code for the list of the old entries.

Comment: As per my knowledge that autocomplete dropdown box cannot be edited with CSS and is not part of the DOM. You will have to look for some other way or disable that browser autocomplete

Answer (score 1):

To add CSS you need to debug in chrome through this way

In Chrome Dev Tools, go to the most parent element on which the dynamic HTML is loaded.
Right click on the parent and add a debugger by doing this,

```
Break On > Subtree modifications.
```

For your reference
https://camerondwyer.com/2018/07/11/how-to-inspect-dynamic-html-elements-that-keep-disappearing-in-chrome/

Comment: So sorry, I meant the old entries, not the autocompleted.

Comment: It is interesting but it doesn't look to work in my case or I misunderstand something.

Comment: Are u talking about chrome autofill ?

Comment: No, I don't use chrome autofill. In my case the break freeze the black list but I can't really read the CCS involved because I lose the focus on my list when I move the cursor.